# liquibase Oracle ORA-00942

Tags: oracle, liquibase

when calling liquibase migrate, generatechangelog, etc... with an Oracle database , we allways get the ORA-00942 error when liquibase calls the oracle jdbcdriver for metadata

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:395)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:802)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)
```

Comment: ...............................................

Comment: I suggest you to improve your example by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Found the issue by tracing the logging in the ojdbc_g driver. It turns out that   getSchemas() in the jdbcdriver queries ´ALL_USERS` view in Oracle

`DatabaseMetaData metadata=conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs2=metadata.getSchemas();`

`SELECT username AS table_schem,null as table_catalog  FROM all_users ORDER  BY table_schem`
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

In our database, ALL_USERS view does not exist, so I created the view again in the standard Oracle way

`CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "ALL_USERS" ("USERNAME", "USER_ID", "CREATED")
...`

Comment: If `all_users` did not exist in your Oracle installation then your installation is seriously screwed up. I would rather assume your Oracle user did not have the `select` privilege on that view (although that is very unusual and could also indicate a problem with your installation)

Comment: or just no permissions on the sys.all_users view :)

Comment: That's what I meant with "*your Oracle user did not have the select privilege on that view*" - which is also _very_ unusual